# If $S$ is a subspace of $X$, then the relative closure of a set in $S$ is $S$ intersected with the closure in $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be a subspace of a topological space $X$ and let $E$ be a subset of $S$.
Then the relative clousre of $E$ in $S$ is $E^*\cap S$, where $E^*$ is the closure of $E$ in $X$.

This problem is very hard to me.
Tomorrow topology mid-exam,please help me.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your "then ... " is the question:

By definition of the subspace topology (relative toplogy) of $S \subseteq X$ a set $A \subseteq S$ is *closed* iff there is a *closed* subset $B \subseteq X$ such that $S \cap B = A$.

The *closure* of a set $C$ is the intersection of *all closed* sets containing $C$.

Let $C_S(E)$ be the closure of $E$ w.r.t the relative topology of $S$ and $C_X(E)$ be the closure of $E$ w.r.t the "ambient" topology of $X$. Now write down the corresponding closures as "big" intersections, insert the definition for closed sets in the relative space $S$ and think!